# How do I run site-specific user scripts in Safari?

Tags: javascript, safari, navigator

I created a javascript user script for one website. I would like that my navigator detect automatically when I am on this website and execute the script.

Is it possible to run an injected script on a specific site only?

Answer (score 9):

Yes, this is [possible](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/MessagesandProxies/MessagesandProxies.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009977-CH14-SW2). Apple has written up a guide. Note the bolded part towards the end.

> ## Adding a Script
>
> To add an injected script, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Create an extension folder—open Extension Builder, click +, choose New Extension, give it a name and location.
> 2. Drag your script file into the extension folder.
> 3. Click New Script under Injected Extension Content in Extension Builder, as illustrated in Figure 10-1:

[image: Figure 10-1 Specifying injected content]

> You can choose to inject your script as a Start Script or an End Script. An End Script executes when the DOM is fully loaded—at the time the onload attribute of a body element would normally fire. Most scripts should be injected as End Scripts.
>   A Start Script executes when the document has been created but before the webpage has been parsed. If your script blocks unwanted content it should be a Start Script, so it executes before the page displays.
>
> Choose your script file from the pop-up menu.
>   You can have both Start and End Scripts. You can have more than one script of each type.
>
> **In order for your scripts to be injected, you must specify either Some or All website access for your extension.** You can have your script apply to a single webpage, all webpages, or only certain webpages—pages from certain domains, for example. For details, see [the description of whitelists and blacklists in Access and Permissions](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/ExtensionPermissions/ExtensionPermissions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009977-CH8-SW1).

From that last link ([this one](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/ExtensionPermissions/ExtensionPermissions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009977-CH8-SW1)), this is the important picture:

[image: extension website access]

This is what you want to use to blacklist/whitelist sites.